# Enable http2 on Debian 11 Bullseye and Apache 2.4.41

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, http2

I'm testing Debian 11 Bullseye with Apache 2.4.41 and I'm trying to activate HTTP2

I did some things :

```
sudo a2enmod http2
```

It returns : `Module http2 already enabled`

Then I put this line on my SSL/HTTPS virtualhost :

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

After having restarted the Apache service, my test is not Ok and returns HTTP/1.1 request. I tested with a curl command and via https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

Is there a problem with the version of Debian or Apache ? Or something else ?

Comment: Two things.  Is the Protocols directive in the right spot?  Is the SSL cipher strong enough?  See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html, "choose a strong SSLCipherSuite".